# How can I make an installation USB for Windows 10 in elementary OS?

Tags: microsoft-windows, usb-drive, live-cd

I have no problem with making Linux Live USBs, but how do I make an installation USB for Windows in GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winusb/) can do that. It is a bit buggy but it gets the job done.

[UNetBootin used to be able to do it too](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html), but I'm not sure if it still works.

If both these options don't work, you could install a Windows virtual machine and create the ISO from there. [Microsoft profides free Windows VM ISO's for 90 days.](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Comment: WinUSB is too old, it doesn't support Windows 10, it seems that virtual machine is my only choice.

Answer (score 1):

To create windows live usb, you can use [WinUSB](http://onetransistor.blogspot.in/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html).
But WinUSB is a third-party software, we need to add [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/381560/439451) to install.

Before that recommended reading: [How can I identify a PPA is safe or not](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2938/how-can-i-identify-a-ppa-is-safe-or-not).

Also UNetBootin really can't be used to create Windows bootable usb sticks, always errors.

---

You can also create live usb using `gnome-disk-utility`

Install from **Software center** (search `disks`),

Or from terminal command: `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Instructions:

- Open `disks`--> select respective `usb`,

  Now click on *More actions* (double wheel shape) -->select *Restore Disk Image* --> navigate to `.iso` folder --> select `.iso` --> *Start restoring*

  [image: Imgur]

Comment: Both of them failed.

Comment: thanks, waiting for reply. "both" means? `disks` and `winUSB`? @JulianLai

Comment: @JulianLai are you comfortable with `CLI`?

Comment: Yes, both of Gnome-Disk-Utility and winUSB, but I have found the solution, just make the disk become GPT partition, and move the file in the iso to my USB disk.